# Event handling differences between C# & VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, timer, event-handling

NET gurus... How would you convert this very chunk into VB?

```
this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
this.timer.Elapsed+=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ManageThreads);
this.timer.Start();
```

When I use an online converter (Telerik), the middle line converts like this:

```
Me.timer.Elapsed += New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ManageThreads)
```

with 2 errors: 
1- "Public eventElapsed is an event and cannot be called directly. Use raiseEvent
2- Delegate requires an Adess Of expression. Do I simply add "Address Of" ?

Any clue warmly welcome.

Comment: Crappy converter, this is pretty basic.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for adding event handlers is very different between C# and VB.NET and as you've discovered Telerik doesn't handle that difference very well.

**C# add handler syntax:**

```
<object>.<event> += <event_handler_function>
```

**VB add handler syntax:**

```
add handler <object>.<event>, addressof <event_handler_function>
```

There is another catch you might run into with VB event handling: The object you're adding an event handler for has to be declared at class-scope. E.g. you cannot add a handler to a locally-created object (within a method) and return it or add it to a collection. So you basically have a class-level temp variable when you need to do things dynamically.

Good luck.

Comment: For have VB.NET to automatically wire an event to something using `Handles` keyword, that thing must be declared at class scope as an auto-event-property using the `WithEvents` keyword, but I'm pretty sure that restriction doesn't apply with manual AddHandler/RemoveHandler code; am I mistaken?

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect. You only have that restriction when declaring an object `WithEvents` if you manually wire up events, you can declare it where you like

Answer (score 3):

something strange returns this converter

Try:
AddHandler Me.timer.Elapsed, AddressOf ManageThreads

Add and remove event handlers dynamically in .NET
http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/EventHandler.aspx